# How can I get rid of extra commas in Export/Import?

Tags: export, import

Consider the following example of trying to export the following table:

```
Export["test.dat", {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}, "Table"];
```

Now I import to see what I get:

```
Import["test.dat", "Table"]
{{{1,,1}, {2,,2}}, {{3,, 3}, {4,,4}}}
```

which contains extra undesirable commas. I've trying making the data type a "List" but that possessing an issue in which elements are not separated by commas. How can I fix this problem so the the imported table is the same as I exported?

Comment: If I only have the possibilty to Import as a txt how could I possibly get rid of the commas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is you are saving as text (you can see by looking at the FullForm of the Import[]). One way to fix it is to save to a .csv format, for instance

```
Export["test.csv", {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}]
```

Then you can import it back using

```
Import["test.csv"]
```

And you get the data you started with.

Comment: Hi, if I am using your suggestion of exporting in *.csv format, I cannot plot or use the imported data as normal?!
Export["test.csv", {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}];
Test1 = Import["test.csv"];
ListPlot[Test1]

Comment: The problem is that reading back gives a list of strings instead of an expression. To plot, use ListPlot[ToExpression@Test1]

Answer (score 13):

Another way:

```
Export["test.dat", {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}, "Table"];

Import["test.dat", "TSV"]
```

Comment: Huge thanks! I had already saved results of a long run using `Export["dc3.dat", results]` and the `"TSV"` turned out to be what I needed to read it.

Answer (score 5):

Another format especially suited for large amounts of multidimensional data is [`HDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HDF.html)
 (or also `HDF5`). It's overkill for your small example, but maybe you have larger sets in mind so that you could use this:

```
Export["test1.hdf", {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}];

Import["test1.hdf", {"Datasets", "Dataset1"}]

(* ==> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

To get something *Mathematica* will like, use

```
Export["test.m", {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}]
```

This will produce a file with the contents:

> (* Created by Wolfram Mathematica 8.0 : www.wolfram.com *)
>   {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{3, 3}, {4, 4}}}