# import list of lists list-wise

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import

I produce several times automatically a number of different lists of varying length and structure like:

```
listA = {{100, 1.7*^10, 2.08*^9}, {105, 1.91*^10, 1.02*^9}, {110, 
2.5*^10, 3.08*^9}};
listB = {{126, 27.6, 3.19}, {131, 29.21, 3.2}};
listC = {3.84, 2.9, 5.90, 4.2, 1.3, 0.91, 1.19, 1.5, 2.79, 2.9};
```

Those I export via: `Export["lists.txt", {listA, listB, listC}, "Table"]`. I know, that I can import them as a whole `Import["lists.txt", "Table"]` but I would like to automatically import them list-wise similar to the following fantasy code:

```
list1 = Import["lists.txt", listA]
list2 = Import["lists.txt", listB]
list3 = Import["lists.txt", listC]
```

But this doesn't work. And since my lists have varying length, I can't use `Part` after the import process, since I don't know which length the listA has in the specific case.

Is there an import procedure, which can be used? Do I have to use another export method in order to enable an easier import?

Comment: what is wrong with `{list1, list2, list3} = Import["lists.txt", "Table"]`?

Comment: you don't need to know the lengths of individual lists to use `Part`, that is,  `imp=Import["lists.txt","Table"]; imp[[1]]` is just fine to get the first list. Similarly, for `imp[[2]]`, `imp[[3]]`.

Comment: @kglr Perfect, those are two solutions at once. The first one is exactly, what I searched for. In case you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
{list1, list2, list3} = Import["lists.txt", "Table"]
```

Alternatively,

```
imp = Import["lists.txt", "Table"];
list1 = imp[[1]]
list2 = imp[[2]]
```

etc.

Comment: there is a problem with this method since in the lists A and B the commas get doubled during import. Independent which of those methods I use, I get for `imp[[2]]`: {"{126,", "27.6,", "3.19}", "{131,", "29.21,", "3.2}"}. Has this something to do with the "Table"?

Comment: Ah, I found something here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16141/how-can-i-get-rid-of-extra-commas-in-export-import But for me it is not really satisfying, why does it not work with txt?